# Selecting a distinct date by day only from datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Executing this command brings me the following (all the dates from all columns, so it essentially did the same thing as SELECT date without distinct):

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM daily ORDER BY date DESC

2013-02-12 16:40:52
2013-02-06 11:48:49
2013-02-06 11:36:41
2013-02-06 11:35:59
2013-02-04 19:38:12
2013-02-04 18:12:30
2013-02-04 09:58:41
2013-02-04 09:43:01
2013-02-04 09:35:51
2013-02-04 09:30:22
2013-02-04 09:24:57
2013-02-04 09:21:09
2013-02-04 08:50:13
```

What I need:

```
2013-02-12
2013-02-06
2013-02-04
```

1. Is there any way to alter my date table and convert it to YYYY-MM-DD instead?
2. If not, is there a way to select distinct dates based only on the day?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which database? Oracle, SQL Server, Teradata, MySQL?

Comment: You realize we're all playing guessing games -- why not tell us which database???

Comment: Re-tagged based on OP's edit to the question title.

Answer (score 12):

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(Current_Timestamp, '%c %d %Y') from dual;
+--------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(Current_Timestamp, '%c %d %Y') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 2 12 2013                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

of course you would be using your 'daily' table.

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%c %d %Y') from daily;
```

or maybe you want

```
mysql> select * from daily group by DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%c %d %Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple use DATE() function.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date)
    FROM daily
    ORDER BY date
    DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME,[DATE]),23)) AS DT  
FROM DAILY
ORDER BY DT ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found on large data sets > N millions, grouping by DATE_FORMAT can be 10-20% slower than using;

```
 GROUP BY someid,year(date),month(date),day(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have just added a small part to sgeddes answer which was close to working for me but I had to as the : AS date_change so I can list the values.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(yourdate, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_change FROM 
daily ORDER BY (yourdate) DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $test = $row['date_change'];
    echo $test.'<br>';



  }

} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use `DATE(date)` to return just the date.  If you want to format it, use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(yourdate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM daily ORDER BY DATE(yourdate) DESC
```

You cannot change the way the database stores these values.

And here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f50527/6

Answer (score 0):

In Access DB

```
SELECT DISTINCT Format(date, 'Short Date')
  FROM daily
 ORDER BY Format(date, 'Short Date') DESC;
```

Comment: *"Access DB"*? This question is about MySQL, not Access DB.

Comment: bro questioner not mention any database

Comment: Please read the question carefully. It says "in MySQL" at the end of the question title. It also says "mysql" in the tags under the question. You can also read the other answers which are all for MySQL.

Comment: @Pang oh right i actually read reply comments where lot of users asking about database may he edit his question later :)