# Counting distinct days from DateTime in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have DB table that logs request with an IP column and a DateTime stamp. I'm trying to fetch this data in a way that makes me count the number of days a certain IP has made requests. I'm using Laravel's query builder.

So far, this is what i've got:

```
$data = DB::table('requests')
                    ->groupBy('ip')
                    ->select('ip', 
                             DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT created_at) as days'), 
                             DB::raw('COUNT(*) as requests'))
                    ->orderBy('days', 'desc')
                    ->take(50)
                    ->get();
```

My problem is that the timestamp also holds hours, minutes and seconds. So the "days" count will be about the same as the number of total requests. I want to only count the number of days active.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If field `created_at` is *TIMESTAMP*:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) as days
```

or if field is *DATETIME*:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(created_at)) as days
```

Comment: or `COUNT(DISTINCT TO_DAYS(created_at)) as days` I think.

Comment: @Fnatte: [TO_DAY()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) accepts date as paramater and not timestamp.

Comment: @Fnatte: I am not sure I would use this function, since first example is `SELECT TO_DAYS(950501);` looks like timestamp, but it is short for `1995-05-01`. `TO_DAYS()` works for dates from `0000-01-01`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use DATE_FORMAT to do what you want. 
Take a look at this question: 
[Selecting a distinct date by day only from datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844186/selecting-a-distinct-date-by-day-only-from-datetime-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-mys)